# List file names within a server with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

When I try to list the files within a server named Neubox using the following JavaScript code, it doesn't show up (the following function is responsible for that, below I will leave the complete code, thank you very much for any kind of help you can provide to help me solve my error).

```
function uploadOptionsData() { clearTableData();
const selectElement = document.getElementById("file-select");
const folderPath = "EstPil";
const fileExtension = ".json";

fetch(folderPath)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const html = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");
        const fileList = Array.from(html.querySelectorAll("a"))
            .map(link => link.getAttribute("href"))
            .filter(href => href.endsWith(fileExtension))
            .map(href => {
                let fileName = decodeURIComponent(href.replace(folderPath, "").replace(fileExtension, "").replace('PagWeb', ""));
                fileName = fileName.replace(/_/g, " ");
                const regex = /[^\w\s]/gi;
                return fileName.replace(regex, "");
            });

        fileList.forEach(fileName => {
            const optionElement = document.createElement("option");
            optionElement.textContent = fileName;
            optionElement.value = folderPath + fileName.replace(/ /g, "_") + fileExtension;
            selectElement.appendChild(optionElement);
        });

        // Add an event listener to the dropdown menu that listens for a change event
        selectElement.addEventListener("change", function () {
            let selectedFile = selectElement.value.replace(folderPath, "");
            selectedFile = folderPath + '/' + selectedFile;
            getData(selectedFile);
            createMap(selectedFile);
            changeTypeCalendar(selectedFile);
        });
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));

changeTypeCalendar(selectedFile);
}
```

I am getting the following errors. Thank you in advance for any help that can be provided.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU66R.png)

**Javascript Code**

```
document.querySelector("#interval").addEventListener('change', changeTypeCalendar.bind(document.querySelector("#interval"))); document.querySelector("#export-btn").addEventListener('click', exportData);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

// Call the function to load options when the page loads uploadOptionsData(); });

function clearTableData() { const responseElement = document.querySelector('#response'); responseElement.innerHTML = ""; }

// Function to reset all options to their original state function resetOptions() { // Get the select elements const intervalSelect = document.querySelector("#interval"); const dateSelect = document.querySelector("#date"); const fileSelect = document.querySelector("#file-select");

// Remove all existing options intervalSelect.innerHTML = ""; dateSelect.innerHTML = ""; fileSelect.innerHTML = ""; clearTableData();

// Reload the options uploadOptionsData(); }

let selectedFile;

function uploadOptionsData() {
clearTableData();

const selectElement = document.getElementById("file-select");
const folderPath = "EstPil";
const fileExtension = ".json";

fetch(folderPath)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const html = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");
    const fileList = Array.from(html.querySelectorAll("a"))
      .map(link => link.getAttribute("href"))
      .filter(href => href.endsWith(fileExtension))
      .map(href => {
        let fileName = decodeURIComponent(href.replace(folderPath, "").replace(fileExtension, "").replace('PagWeb', ""));
        fileName = fileName.replace(/_/g, " ");
        const regex = /[^\w\s]/gi;
        return fileName.replace(regex, "");
      });

    fileList.forEach(fileName => {
      const optionElement = document.createElement("option");
      optionElement.textContent = fileName;
      optionElement.value = folderPath + fileName.replace(/ /g, "_") + fileExtension;
      selectElement.appendChild(optionElement);
    });

    // Add an event listener to the dropdown menu that listens for a change event
    selectElement.addEventListener("change", function() {
        let selectedFile = selectElement.value.replace(folderPath, "");
        selectedFile = folderPath + '/' + selectedFile
        getData(selectedFile);
        createMap(selectedFile);
        changeTypeCalendar(selectedFile); 
      });
        
       
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));

  changeTypeCalendar(selectedFile);

}

function getData(selectedFile) {

clearTableData();

// Get the selected interval
const intervalValue = document.querySelector("#interval").value;

// Get the selected date from the input field
const dateInput = document.getElementById('date');
const selectedDate = dateInput.value;

// Validate if both interval and selected file are present
if (selectedFile) {
    // Create a new instance of XMLHttpRequest to send an HTTP request
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Open a GET request to get the selected file
    xhr.open('GET', selectedFile, true);

    // Send the HTTP request
    xhr.send();

    // Listen to the state change of the request
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        // If the response state and status code are correct
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            // Parse the response content as JSON
            let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            // Select the HTML element where the data will be displayed
            let responseElement = document.querySelector('#response');

            // Clear the previous content of the HTML element
            responseElement.innerHTML = '';

            // Format the selected date
            const formattedDate = new Date(selectedDate).toISOString().slice(0, 10);

            // Filter the data based on the selected date and interval
            let filteredData = data.filter(item => item.date == formattedDate && item.interval == intervalValue);

            // If there is no data for the selected date and interval
            if (filteredData.length === 0) {
                responseElement.innerHTML = 'No data available for the selected date and interval.';
                return;
            }

            // Create a table to display the data
            let table = document.createElement('table');

            // Create a table header
            let thead = document.createElement('thead');
            let tr = document.createElement('tr');

            // Add table headers
            let headers = Object.keys(filteredData[0]);
            headers.forEach(header => {
                let th = document.createElement('th');
                th.textContent = header;
                tr.appendChild(th);
            });

            // Add the table header to the table
            thead.appendChild(tr);
            table.appendChild(thead);

            // Create a table body
            let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

            // Add table rows and cells for each data item
            filteredData.forEach(item => {
                let row = document.createElement('tr');
                headers.forEach(header => {
                    let cell = document.createElement('td');
                    cell.textContent = item[header];
                    row.appendChild(cell);
                });
                tbody.appendChild(row);
            });

            // Add the table body to the table
            table.appendChild(tbody);

            // Add the table to the response element
            responseElement.appendChild(table);
        }
    };
}
}
function exportData() { // Get the data from the HTML table const tableData = document.querySelector('#response');

// Create a new XLSX workbook instance
const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();

// Convert the HTML table data to a worksheet
const worksheet = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(tableData);

// Add the worksheet to the workbook
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, 'Data');

// Create a Blob object from the workbook
const workbookBlob = new Blob([XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' })], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });

// Create a download URL for the Blob object
const url = URL.createObjectURL(workbookBlob);

// Create a temporary link element
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = url;
link.download = 'data.xlsx';

// Programmatically trigger a click event on the link element
link.click();

// Clean up the URL and link element
URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
link.remove();
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Pruebas Datos MOCALTAMA</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="section">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s4">
                    
                    <label for="interval">Intervalo:</label>
                    <select id="interval" name="interval" class="browser-default">
                        <option value="daily">Daily</option>
                        <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col s4">
                    <label for="fecha">Selecciona la fecha:</label>
                    <input type="date" id="date" name="fecha" max="" required>
                </div>

                <div class="col s4">
                    <label for="file-select">Seleccione una ubicacion:</label>
                    <select id="file-select" name="file-select" class="browser-default"></select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- <div class="col s6">
                <button class="btn" id="btn">
                    Consultar
                </button>
            </div> -->

            <div id="export-btn" class="btn" style="color: white">
                Exportar datos
            </div>

            <div id="map" style="height: 400px;"></div>

            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Latitud</th>
                        <th>Longitud</th>
                        <th>Día</th>
                        <th>Hora</th>
                        <th>CO2</th>
                        <th>VOC</th>
                        <th>Humedad Relativa</th>
                        <th>Temperatura</th>
                        <th>PM 1.0 (Grimm)</th>
                        <th>PM 2.5 (Grimm)</th>
                        <th>PM 10 (Grimm)</th>
                        <th>PM 1.0 (TSI)</th>
                        <th>PM 2.5 (TSI)</th>
                        <th>PM 10 (TSI)</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody id="response">

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section" id="respuesta"></div>

    
    <script src="DocXLSX/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Map/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="Map/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: FWIW, you can simplify your map, filter, map by simply looping through **html.querySelectorAll("a[href$='.json']")** that will get all of the anchors that end with .json.

Comment: Also I would check out [mcve] and [ask] as that will assist you

Comment: I also get a 403 when I visit that URL in my browser.